# Can not scroll in div with fixed height (parent)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

So I have got a chat div on the right side, I just want to make this scrollable because when I have more messages I can only see the last few ones.
I've got this code so far:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-8 px-0 h-100">
            <div id="RightBox" class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
                <div id="Messages" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-end overflow-auto px-2 py-1">
                    <div><p class="float-start px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">5</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-start px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">lmlml</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-start px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">qzdqz</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-end px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">Melih</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-end px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">Kek</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-start px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">Yo Im a seller</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-end px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">Ik ben een customer</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-start px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">Aangenaam ik ben een seller genaamd gucci</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-start px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">yoyo</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-start px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">Hallo ik ben Melih en ik leef in belgie Id wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking abou</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-end px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">qzdqzdqzdqzdqzd</p></div>
                        <div><p class="float-end px-2 py-1 mb-2 border rounded" style="max-width: 75%;">Hallo ik ben Melih en ik leef in belgie Id wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking abouHallo ik ben Melih en ik leef in belgie Id wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking abouHallo ik ben Melih en ik leef in belgie Id wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking abouHallo ik ben Melih en ik leef in belgie Id wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking abouHallo ik ben Melih en ik leef in belgie Id wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking abouHallo ik ben Melih en ik leef in belgie Id wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking abouHallo ik ben Melih en ik leef in belgie Id wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking about wtf you are talking abou</p></div></div>
                <div id="Actions" class="flex-shrink-1 px-2 py-2">
                    <div class="row px-0">
                        <div class="col-8 pe-0">
                            <input type="hidden" name="chat_id" id="chat_id" value="1">
                            <input type="text" class="customInput cBorderBlack py-2" placeholder="Message" id="message">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 ps-0">
                            <button class="customButton py-2 btn-outline-success  fw-bolder border-success" id="sendBtn">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should add `overflow-auto` to your div

Comment: Which one tho??

Comment: @MELo You can add it to whichever parent contains all the messages. So, I assume here it's that top div in your code sample.

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to the actual question. Since this is a HTML/CSS question (client side layout), you should remove the PHP tag and then post the generated HTML instead of the PHP source. It's always easiest to first build the HTML/CSS to make it as you want. When that's done, you can start replacing the test content with dynamic content from PHP. If you do both at the same time, you have much more to debug to find potential issues.

Comment: @JamesWilliam I did nothing changed

Comment: Also make sure it is not scrollable by clicking inside of the message box and try to scroll with mouse. The scrollbar if it is there, would be hidden by default in modern browsers

Comment: @M.Eriksson thanks for letting me know, will take your advice!

Comment: @Huangism tried not working ;c

Comment: @MELo you would need to create the problem on here, without seeing the css, it is hard to say what is causing the issue

Comment: @MELo The code sample's pretty messy and missing a lot of context, wanna setup a https://codepen.io sample and lets see if we can help? ☺️